# How to get file metadata from external drive in Python?

Tags: python, directory, metadata, filenames

I wrote a Python script that collects file metadata (filename, creation date, creation time, last modified data, last modified time) from a file directory. However, when the directory is a path that is located in an external hard drive the script doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from os.path import basename
import datetime
import time
def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    print st
    return st.st_size

#get last modified date
def getMTime(filename):
    fileModTime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    return fileModTime

#get creation date
def getCTime(filename):
    fileModTime = os.path.getctime(filename)
    return fileModTime

#get data from directory

MyDirectory = "H:\0_tempfiles\150115_Portfolio\Work\Work\BarBackUp"
MyExtension = ".jpg"

#write to file
WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\Admin\Downloads\demo\\"
MyTxtFile = WorkingDirectory + "fileData6.txt"

delim = ";"

with open(MyTxtFile, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(delim.join(["FILENAME", "FILESIZE", "mDATE","mTIME",
                      "cDATE","cTIME"]) + "\n")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MyDirectory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(MyExtension):
            #get File Name
            a = (os.path.join(root, file))
            #print a
            filename = a
            MyFileName = basename(a)

            #get File Size
            MyFileSize = getSize(filename) / 1000
            print MyFileName + " >>> file size: " + str(MyFileSize) + "Kb"

            #get modification time V2
            modTimeV2 = getMTime(filename)
            modTimeV2 = time.strftime("%Y/%d/%m;%I:%M:%S   %p", \
                                      time.localtime(modTimeV2))
            print "time modified: " + str(modTimeV2)

            #get creation time 
            creTime = getCTime(filename)
            creTime = time.strftime("%Y/%d/%m;%I:%M:%S %p", \
                                    time.localtime(creTime))
            print "time created: " + str(creTime) 

            #--------
            #write data to file
            entry = delim.join([str(MyFileName), str(MyFileSize), \
                                str(modTimeV2), str(creTime)]) + "\n"
            f.write(entry)

   print "<<<<<<everything went fine>>>>>>"
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work', do you have an error, no info at all? Please be more specific.

Comment: also, experiment to see if all of the operations you're doing on the directory fail or just some of them (or just seeing the directory at all). Minimal and complete!

Comment: @EspartaPalma the script when used with directories from external drives doesn't have any error, just no info at all. While with paths from my C drive it works returning the list of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Your "MyDirectory" variable has escape characters in it. Try adding an r in front of the quotations:

```
MyDirectory = r"H:\0_tempfiles\150115_Portfolio\Work\Work\BarBackUp"
```

or

```
MyDirectory = "H:/0_tempfiles/150115_Portfolio/Work/Work/BarBackUp"
```

or

```
MyDirectory = "H:\\0_tempfiles\\150115_Portfolio\\Work\\Work\\BarBackUp"
```

Comment: Thanks! This tip fixed it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you share a few sources where I can read more about file directory syntax and understand why it was working locally but not with a file path from an external drive?
Thanks!

Comment: It is actually a problem with your string usage. Take a look at documentation on "escape characters" in strings.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: It is generally a good idea to write filepaths using front slashes: "C:/abc/def/file.ext" to avoid having issues with escape characters. Placing an "r" in front of your string definition tells the interpretter to treat your string as a "raw string" which converts escape characters to normal backslashes.